# Error connecting to Google Cloud Storage: 'missing project id'

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am getting the following error when I attempt to access Google Cloud Storage:

```
GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access     denied.</Message><Details>Missing project id</Details></Error>
```

I have the correct project id specified in my .boto config file, and I have read/write access to the bucket I'm trying to access.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Is the "default_project_id" variable set in your .boto file under the "[GSUtil]" section?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to run `gsutil config` & give the name of your project -- that will auto-gen your ~/.boto file.